# I want to put some validation on a table header and body, using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I want to put a validation on a table, that until anything is dropped to any column cell user should not be able to drop anything on that cell header. But I am not able to figure out how to make a connection between table header and cell of every column.

This is my controller:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.tableSelection = {};
      $scope.tableInputColSelection={};//added for ccgbase 2251
    $scope.tableOutputColSelection={};
    $scope.output_columns=[1];
    $scope.input_columns=[1];
      $scope.data = [];
      $scope.rows = [1, 2, 3]; 

      $scope.removeSelectedItems = function(){
       // $scope.rows = $scope.rows.filter(function(item, index){
         // return !($scope.tableSelection[index] !== undefined && $scope.tableSelection[index]); 
       if(Object.keys($scope.tableSelection).length>0){
                                 for (var i = $scope.rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                                  if ($scope.tableSelection[i]) {
                                    //delete row from data
                                      if($scope.rows.length>1){
                                      $scope.rows.splice(i, 1);
                                      }

                                     delete $scope.tableSelection[i];
                                }
                                 }
                                }
                                if(Object.keys($scope.tableInputColSelection).length>0){
                                    for (var i = $scope.input_columns.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                                      if ($scope.tableInputColSelection[i]) {
                                        //delete row from data
                                          if($scope.input_columns.length>1){
                                            $scope.input_columns.splice(i, 1);
                                          }
                                        delete $scope.tableInputColSelection[i];
                                      }
                                }

                                }
                                if(Object.keys($scope.tableOutputColSelection).length>0){
                                    for (var i = $scope.output_columns.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                                      if ($scope.tableOutputColSelection[i]) {
                                        //delete row from data
                                          if($scope.output_columns.length>1){
                                            $scope.output_columns.splice(i, 1);
                                          }
                                        delete $scope.tableOutputColSelection[i];
                                      }
                                    }
                                }





      }
      $scope.addNewRow = function() {
        //set row selected if is all checked

        $scope.rows.push({
          id: $scope.rows.length,
          name: 'Name ' + $scope.rows.length
        });
      };
     $scope.addInput= function () {
                                for(var i=0;i<1;i++){
                                    $scope.input_columns.push({
                                        id:$scope.input_columns.length,
                                        name: 'Name'+$scope.input_columns.length
                                    });
                                    }
                            },

         $scope.addOutput= function () {
                                for(var i=0;i<1;i++){
                                    $scope.output_columns.push({
                                        id:$scope.output_columns.length,
                                        name:'Name'+$scope.output_columns.length
                                    });
                                    }
                            }

This is the plunker link:
http://plnkr.co/edit/IpUjN5wiwv3q8XT2y864?p=preview
```

I want to perform some more validations, but for that i need to figure out how to get the entry of a particular column including header and cell of all columns individually.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get idea about how the complexity is your object. But the following idea may help you.

If the array is like following you can easily do validation.

> Headers = [Header1,Header2,Header3,Header4];
>
> Header1ColumnValues = These are array of values.  Columns
>   = These are array of values.
>
> Columns =
>   [[header1Columnvalues],[header2ColumnValues],[Header3ColumnValues],[Header4ColumValues]];

If you want to access the columns 1 and and Header 1, then you can access like

> Headers[0], columns[0], for the 2n, Headers[1], Columns[1]

Comment: But this solution works when data is entered sequentially, suppose if data is dropped on 5th column,4th row..Then how to identify the index of the cell.

Comment: You can get the index from ng-repeat and have a call back function for on drop. Pass this ng-repeat index to this call back function. Then you will get the index of column. Row will be identified based on the data in which position. Hope this will help you..

Comment: I tried some solution but I am not getting $index value on drop function. It is giving $index undefined error on html page itself. Can you please help me in this for how to get index of each cell when any element is dropped

Comment: I have added my plunker here on input header I haven't added $index on drop so it is working. While on output header it is not allowing to drop. I am not getting how to pass $index in drop method. On check box I am able to get the index because of the checkbox selection and able to delete the entire column and row based on that selection. But not getting how to get the index on drop of any element

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97929/discussion-between-fatema-rangwala-and-jeeva-jsb).